# find the number of items between two items in a list

Tags: python, list, algorithm, math

I want to be able to find the difference between two items in a list. The exact items I want to find are generated randomly and are their own elements. For simplicity I will declare them as A and D. How would I find the number of items between these two items? The answer I would be looking for in this scenario would be 3.

```
list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']

item1 = 'A'
item2 = 'D'
```

Comment: Use `index()` to get the positions, then subtract the results.

Comment: why would it be 3 instead of 2 or 4?

Comment: `abs(list.index('D') - list.index('A'))`

Comment: BTW, don't use `list` as a variable name. It overwrites the built-in function.

Answer (score 2):

```
list.index(item2) - list.index(item1)
```

Answer (score 1):

[tomtomfox's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68146015/2422776) is of course correct. However, it has a built-in inefficiency that the first several items up to `item1` are checked twice. If it's guaranteed that `item2` comes after `item1`, this is redundant, and if the list is large, it may be noticeable. A slightly less concise but more performant solution would be to use the index of `item1` as the starting point for searching for `item2`:

```py
def distance(lst, item1, item2):
    index1 = lst.index(item1)
    index2 = lst.index(item2, index1)
    return index2 - index2
```

Answer (score 0):

Build a dictionary from items to their index in the list. This takes linear time and space.

Once this is done, each query is O(1): find the indices and take the difference.